# getting the second from the list instead of the selected one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to save on the selected option but always getting the second one (after selecting )with my code.. why?

```
$(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").change(function () {
    debugger;
    localStorage.setItem('ChosenDateIndexLS', $(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").find(":selected")[0].index);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ChosenDateIndexLS is :: ", localStorage.getItem('ChosenDateIndexLS'));
    $(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").prop('selectedIndex', localStorage.getItem('ChosenDateIndexLS')); 
});
```

The aspx:

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dateTimeFilter" CssClass="dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dateTimeFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
        onchange="bindControlEvents()" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <label id="dateTimeFilterLabel" runat="server" style="padding-left: 15px" visible="false">
        בחירת מופע לפי תאריך</label>
</div>
```

[HTML Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzq7T.png)

Comment: Can you post your HTML, please?

Comment: Please add the HTML as rendered to the page, as seen by selecting "View Source" in the broswer. Is your javascript firing before the postback caused by asp.net?

Comment: Yeah, @TzipPerkal. A rendered version would be more helpful :)

Comment: Don't post images of code. We can't copy and paste images of code to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @Tico I added above thanks!

Comment: @JonP sorry couldn't copy. will try again

Comment: is your change code executing before the postback. could you stop the postback and see if correct value is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the options are being generated. Instead of using index, you can try saving the `value` of the selected option and applying it afterwards.

```
$(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").change(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('ChosenDateIndexLS', $(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").val());
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ChosenDateIndexLS is :: ", localStorage.getItem('ChosenDateIndexLS'));
    $(".dateTimeFilterIdentifierCls").val(localStorage.getItem('ChosenDateIndexLS')); 
});
```